# Convergence of a sequence of a random variable

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $\Theta$ be uniformly distributed on the interval $[0,2\pi]$. In which of the four senses (a.s., m.s., p., d.) does the following sequence converge? Identify the limits, if they exist, and justify your answers.

The sequence is $(X_n : n\ge 1)\ \ X_n=\cos(n\Theta)$.

Well I think that there's no p. convergence, so also there's no a.s nor m.s.

For convergence in d. sense, I think there's no convergence since the distribution function for $X_n$ is $F(X_n)=\cos^2(n\theta)/2$ for $\theta\in [0,2\pi]$.
Am I right here?

Thanks!

Comment: What is convergence m.s.?

Comment: @0XLR convergence in mean square: https://www.statlect.com/asymptotic-theory/mean-square-convergence

Comment: How did you derive the distribution function $F_{X_n}$? It is not right since it is still in terms of $\theta$ and not the transformed variable $X_n = \cos(n \Theta)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your distribution for $X_n$ is wrong; distribution functions are supposed to be increasing and your $F_{X_n}$ is definitely not increasing.

Notice that if $\Theta \sim U(0, 2\pi)$, then for $n \in \mathbb Z_+$, $n\Theta \sim U(0, 2\pi n)$ and the support of $X_n = \cos(n\Theta)$ is $[-1, +1]$. So for $-1 \leq x \leq +1$
\begin{align*}
F_{X_n}(x) = P[X_n \leq x] &= P[\cos(n\Theta) \leq x] \\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^n P\Big[2\pi (k - 1) + \cos^{-1}(x) \leq n\Theta \leq 2\pi k - \cos^{-1}(x)\Big] \\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{2\pi-2\cos^{-1}(x)}{2\pi n} = 1 - \frac{\cos^{-1}(x)}{\pi}
\end{align*} and $F_{X_n}(x) = 0$ for $x < -1$ while $F_{X_n}(x) = 1$ for $x > +1$.

So since $F_{X_n}$ does not actually depend on $n$ we see that $X_n$ **does in fact converge in distribution** to the random variable $X$ with support $[-1, +1]$ and distribution $F_X(x) = 1 - \frac{\cos^{-1}(x)}{\pi}, -1 \leq x \leq +1$.